# Defining an array with size from a stack variable

Tags: c

This one's got me stumped. If I have a structure:

```
struct MyType
{
  float *data;
}
```

And an init function to allocate some memory for the data:

```
void init(MyType *s, int length)
{
  s->data = (float *)malloc(length*sizeof(float));
}
```

If I declare an array of MyType using a #define it works as expected:

```
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 10
MyType myArr[NUM_ELEMENTS];
for (int i=0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
{
  init(&myArr[i], 1000);
}
```

However, if I declare the array using a variable on the stack, I get strange behavior:

```
int numElements = 10;
MyType myArr[numElements];
...
```

It's hard to explain what the behavior is without going into detail about more of the code which I think will just confuse things. I know that changing back and forth between the #define and the stack variable decides whether it works or not, so I suspect the problem is here somewhere.

My question is: is everything I'm doing above legal and should it work or am I doing something obviously wrong? I want to use the stack variable so I can define the array size at runtime from a config value.

Comment: "It's hard to explain what the behavior is without going into detail" - it's hard to answer this without knowing some context.

Comment: Everything you're trying is legal standard C (C99 or newer).  What compiler are you using?

Comment: You don't have to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Should we be ignoring the fact that you're `init()` invocation in your  "working" loop will not even compile with the `init()` declaration just a few lines above in the previous code snippet?

Comment: @H2CO3: That's why my question wasn't "what am I doing wrong?" My question was "is what I'm doing in the code above legal?"

Comment: Actually I am using g++ with -std=c++0x. So I guess this is C++. But I would like to keep the code C compatible if possible.

Comment: So if you are compiling a C program, why are you using a C++ compiler?  That's your answer, though.  C99-style variable length arrays don't exist in C++.

Comment: If you want the code to be C compatible, don't compile with C++. They are different languages, regardless of the repetitious malarky sold by the "move at your own speed" pundits.

Comment: You want to define the size of the array from a config file at runtime ? Do You know that runtime memory allocation goes to the heap ? so forget about stack if you want runtime control...

Comment: @A4L That's downright wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3 you might want to teach me what's right, my C knowledge is a bit outdated :/

Comment: @A4L The truth is that VLAs can be stored on the stack.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's a C99 feature ([VALs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)) Thanks for pointing!

Comment: @A4L Yes, that's C99-only. You're welcome.

Comment: Well, C99 or newer.  C11 has them, too.  It threw out (at least optionally) lots of other C99 shenanigans, though.

Comment: @CarlNorum (Damn. Yes, I meant C99 or newer. I don't speak English... -.-)

Comment: @H2CO3, I just went to check, and it turns out VLAs are optional in C11.

Comment: @CarlNorum Two errors cancelling each other :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a too late comment:

> Actually I am using g++ with -std=c++0x. So I guess this is C++

So that's it. You can't have variable-length arrays (VLAs) in C++. That's a C99 feature.

Comment: That's interesting. The code I am editing apparently has VLAs all over the place, but it's all using those compiler settings. Why is that working? PS the VLA code was not mine originally if that counts for anything :)

Comment: @tanders12 Sure you're compiling it as C++?

Comment: GCC almost certainly has extensions to support VLAs in C++ code.

Comment: g++ allows it via a compiler extension.  On a side note, VLA's are really just a bad idea, don't even bother with them.

Comment: I'm definitely using g++ with -std=c++0x. I don't know if that guarantees C++ or not

Comment: @tanders12 No, not without a compiler extension. Maybe g++ is just too permissive and turns on GNU extensions by default.

Comment: @EdS. I agree completely but it would be a major overhaul to this codebase to remove all of them. That's why moving forward I am using malloc as shown above. But running into some issues...

Comment: @tanders12: That's fine, my comment was more theoretical in nature.

Comment: Answer accepted on the basis that what I'm doing should not work since I'm using a C++ compiler. I guess I'll need to find a different question in order to figure out what's wrong with my code...